# React: How to use current State in events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a form to submit. Here how my state looks like.

```
const [valueState, setValueState] = useState({
    dr_start_date: null,
    dr_end_date: null,
    s_key: "Staging + Commiting in report",
  });
```

After Updating the state using `setValueState` function, I want to submit the form on a `onClick` event. (My click Function)

```
const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(valueState);
  }
```

> **Output of this State is the starting state. Can someone tell me How to use a state variable in events of functions?**

Note: Here's how I am updating the state.

```
function handleInputOne(event, element) {
    if (typeof event.persist === "function") event.persist();

    const { derive_value_from, ele_def } = element;

    setValueState((prevState) => {
      const newValueState = { ...prevState };
      newValueState[derive_value_from] = event.target.value;
      return newValueState;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use event from input like this :

```
const handleChange = (event)=>{
const {value,name} = event.target
setValue(currentState=>{...currentState,[name]:value})
}
```

and for input component add name prop like this:

```
<input name="dr_start_date" value={value.dr_start_date} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

and to check state update :

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(value)
},[value])
```

this effect will run each time value change.

Comment: Hi Sir, I have Implemented approximately the same code lines. The rest of the Functionality is also working fine. Update state and all is working. 
Problem is when I want to do ``` console.log(valueState) ``` under a function, It is logging the initial stage.

Comment: yes of course react doesn't update state immediately, its asynchronous. to check the state change just use `useEffect`, check edited code.